# How do I call a stored procedure on each of the files in a directory as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, batch-processing, sqlcmd

I'm very green with Batch scripting, but as my client doesn't allow the use of SSIS, this is the only tool I can turn to right now...

I have a folder of flat files, and I want to call a stored procedure on each file.

I can loop through the files, and I can call sqlcmd, but I can't figure out how to pass the name of the file to the stored procedure.

Here's what I have:

```
pushd D:\test
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b') do sqlcmd -S servername -U username -P pword -Q "EXEC db.schema.sp $(the_filename)" -v the_filename = %%i
popd
```

But I'm getting an error:
    Incorrect syntax near '%'

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Remove the spaces around `=`, see examples at the end of [the documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx): `-v the_filename="%%i"`

Comment: @wOxxOm Making that change didn't get rid of the syntax error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pushd D:\test
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b') do (
    sqlcmd -S servername -U username -P pword -Q "EXEC db.schema.sp '%%i'"
)
popd
```

The parentheses are not required, but I like to use them for added clarity.